# Moving player before actually loading the map? (not being admin of the server)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

By accident, I destroyed several full double-chests at once on a multiplayer Minecraft server.

The server immediately crashed due to (probably) the large amount of items. It restarts automatically, but on my next attempt to connect, it immediately crashes again.  I can see other players (out of sight, i.e. they don't load the chunk where it happened) logging in and playing without problem.

The problem is: I can't contact the owner of the server, as he seems to be on vacation, and I have no way to connect the others. He would be able to solve my mess by mcedit or similar tools.

Is there any way to solve this problem from my side? I think of moving my player somewhere else on the map, or even moving it into the Nether before actually logging in (and loading the chunks)?

May be any other solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can't. When you join a server, the chunks get loaded immediately. You will need admin help for this.

Comment: title states (not being admin of the server), so this isn't an answer, but a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/170785)

Comment: Are you serious? This comunity sucks, i just answered his question, not with the answer that he / she want's but it's an answer and it's the real answer. And he / she decides if the answer is useful, not you

Comment: This is a community based website network. If s/he was the one to decide, there wouldn't be review functions.

Comment: Even so, judging the community based on the response to only a first answer... not the way to go. There's still plenty of questions that you could answer, and a lot of different ways to get involved in the community. The [Tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) should be a pretty good starting point. :)

Comment: This is not the first time

Comment: @ardaozkal This is still an answer.  While it certainly isn't a *high quality* answer, this still qualifies as a direct answer to the question.  Remember, the NaA flag isn't for judging the correctness of an answer, but whether there's an attempt to actually *answer the question*.  This does that.  Is it right or wrong?  Doesn't matter.  It's an answer.